# How can I cast and use an object on one line of code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, casting

I'm trying to access a hiddenfield on a parent page from a webcontrol. The below works but I want to do it in one line.

```
HiddenField hiddenFieldPid = (HiddenField)this.Parent.FindControl("HiddenFieldPid");
hiddenFieldPid.Value = ListBox_JobPositions.SelectedValue;
```

Not really sure why this doesn't work but I don't get the Value property appear in intellisense when I do this:

```
(HiddenField)this.Parent.FindControl("HiddenFieldPid").NOOPTIONFORVALUEHERE = ListBox_JobPositions.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add parentheses to get the cast to work in the right place:

```
((HiddenField)this.Parent.FindControl("HiddenFieldPid"))
                         .Value = ListBox_JobPositions.SelectedValue;
```

However be aware that doing this in one line opens you up to several possible exceptions that will be difficult to diagnose.

Answer (score 3):

You're close:

```
((HiddenField)this.Parent.FindControl("HiddenFieldPid")).Value = ListBox_JobPositions.SelectedValue;
```

Essentially, the FindControl method is returning the object, which needs the cast.

Answer (score 0):

```
((HiddenField)this.Parent.FindControl("HiddenFieldPid")).value=ListBox_JobPositions.SelectedValue.toString();
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you were trying to accomplish with this answer.  It looks like all you did was restate the OP's original code.  Were you going somewhere with this or should you simply delete the answer?